# Leave only unique rows in 3 columns out of 4

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
Date                      ID     Type    Value
2020-08-04 03:00:00        1    active     14
2020-08-04 03:00:00        1    active     15
2020-08-04 03:00:00        2    active     16
2020-08-04 03:00:00        2    passive     17
```

I want to remove rows which has same values in columns Date ID Type. So desired result is:

```
Date                      ID     Type    Value
2020-08-04 03:00:00        1    active     14
2020-08-04 03:00:00        2    active     16
2020-08-04 03:00:00        2    passive     17
```

As you see, second row disappeared. How could i do that?

Comment: If your data frame is call is called `df`, then `df[-which(duplicated(df[,c("Date", "ID", "Type")), ]` should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a global id like this with `paste()` and then use `duplicated()`:

```
#Code
mdf[duplicated(mdf$Date,mdf$ID,mdf$Type,fromLast = F),]
```

Output:

```
                Date ID    Type Value
2 04/08/2020 3:00:00  1  active    15
3 04/08/2020 3:00:00  2  active    16
4 04/08/2020 3:00:00  2 passive    17
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
mdf <- structure(list(Date = c("04/08/2020 3:00:00", "04/08/2020 3:00:00", 
"04/08/2020 3:00:00", "04/08/2020 3:00:00"), ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L), Type = c("active", "active", "active", "passive"), Value = 14:17), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to keep the minimum value for a given `ID`, you can use this `dplyr` solution:

```
mdf %>% 
  group_by(Date, ID, Type) %>% 
  mutate(Value = min(Value)) %>% 
  unique()
```

Which gives us:

```
  Date                  ID Type    Value
  <chr>              <int> <chr>   <int>
1 04/08/2020 3:00:00     1 active     14
2 04/08/2020 3:00:00     2 active     16
3 04/08/2020 3:00:00     2 passive    17
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```r
tble = read.table(text='
S.no Date                      ID     Type    Value
1 2020-08-04 03:00:00        1    active     14
2 2020-08-04 03:00:00        1    active     15
3 2020-08-04 03:00:00        2    active     16
4 2020-08-04 03:00:00        2    passive     17')

library(dplyr)

tble %>% distinct(Date, ID, Type, .keep_all=TRUE)
#>         S.no     Date ID    Type Value
#> 1 2020-08-04 03:00:00  1  active    14
#> 3 2020-08-04 03:00:00  2  active    16
#> 4 2020-08-04 03:00:00  2 passive    17
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>